# Find the matching result by postgresql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an issue to get results based on selection in dropdown. I have dropdown with categories. I have three table with associated to each other.

```
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I have generated migration with join table `categories_users` and it has foreign key of both table.

we have to select categories should be matched with users that have those selected categories only.

Now I need to find the result based on above things.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: So far all I've gotten from the above section is, you have a categories dropdown, categories are recursive and users have and belong to many categories. You say "We have to select categories that should match the users categories". So the dropdown contains only the user's categories? I'm confused still.

Comment: We have all categories and those are populated in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You should have

```
class Category
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Comment: I got solution to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo you are creating an association of `Category` with `:categories` instead of `:users`

```
Class Category 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users 
end
```

Comment: I got solution to fix this issue

Comment: Please post it as an answer